# Androidで定期的にサーバーのデータをチェックする方法

Tags: android

連絡先アプリのように定期的にサーバーのデータをチェックして端末のデータを更新する機能を作りたいです。
場合によって通知領域にメッセージを出したりします。

サーバーからのプッシュ型ではなくクライアントからのプル型で実装したいです。皆さんどのように実装されているのでしょう？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

大きく分けて 2 つの方法があります。

1 つは SyncAdapter を使う方法。もう 1 つは AlarmManager を使う方法です。

SyncAdapter は、ContentProvider や AccountManager と密な連携を取るもので、定期的にデータベースのデータを同期するための仕組みです。

AlarmManager は、特定のタイミングや間隔で Intent を飛ばすための仕組みで、その Intent を受け取った時に、データの更新をする処理を走らせることで、SyncAdapter と同じ機能を実現できます。

以下のページを参考にしてみてください。

参考：http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html, http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html, https://github.com/mixi-inc/AndroidTraining/wiki/2.15.-ContentProvider-%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BA%E5%B1%95, http://qiita.com/KeithYokoma/items/17d9bee6612e16393353, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: 補足しておきますと、 AlarmManager のほうが比較的楽に実装できます。それに比べるとSyncManagerはやることがかなり多いですが…格好がつきます。

Comment: さらに補足すると、Sync Adapterは、こちらで指定した同期間隔に基づいてOS側がさらにバッテリーをなるべく節約するようになど微調整します。Sync Adapter側の自動同期はオフにしておいて、AlarmManagerのコールバックからSync Adapterの同期処理をキューに積むなど併用もできます。

Comment: さらに補足すると、SyncAdapterを使った場合 1) OSの設定画面の「アカウント」かどこかに、そのアプリが同期をしている旨が表示され、ユーザが同期をOFFにできます。一般的には好ましい動作だと思いますが、アプリの要件によっては望ましくないかもしれません 2) SyncAdapterはネットワーク通信を使うことを前提にしており、ネットワークがないときは定期処理が呼ばれない、というようなことがドキュメントに書いてあります